# remove object array if equal to value of array

Tags: javascript, arrays

i have a object array and a normal array, i want to remove item in object array if it is equal to my normal array. it is confusing for me to do.

Here's what i have tried so far

```js
var countries = 
[
{ChoicesID: 1, ChoicesName : 'afghanistan'},
{ChoicesID: 2, ChoicesName : 'albania'},
{ChoicesID: 3, ChoicesName : 'algeria'},
{ChoicesID: 4, ChoicesName : 'angola'},
{ChoicesID: 5, ChoicesName : 'argentina'},
{ChoicesID: 6, ChoicesName : 'armenia'}
];

var answer = ['afghanistan','albania','algeria'];

var ChoicesName = new Set(countries.map(d => d.ChoicesName));
var NewCountries = [...ChoicesName, ...answer.filter(d => !ChoicesName.has(countries.find(o => o.ChoicesName === answer)))];
console.log(NewCountries );
```

The expected output should be like this

```
     var NewCountries = 
     [
       {ChoicesID: 4, ChoicesName : 'angola'},
       {ChoicesID: 5, ChoicesName : 'argentina'},
       {ChoicesID: 6, ChoicesName : 'armenia'}
     ];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `filter` and remove if the `answer` has it. created an `answerSet` to get O(1) lookup otherwise can use `includes` but includes is O(m) (m is no of elements in the `answer` array, n is elements in `countries` array)

with set
O(m) + O(n).O(1) = O(n) (given n>m)

with includes
O(n).O(m) = O(nm)

```js
var countries = [{ChoicesID: 1, ChoicesName : 'afghanistan'},{ChoicesID: 2, ChoicesName : 'albania'},{ChoicesID: 3, ChoicesName : 'algeria'},{ChoicesID: 4, ChoicesName : 'angola'},{ChoicesID: 5, ChoicesName : 'argentina'},{ChoicesID: 6, ChoicesName : 'armenia'}];
var answer = ['afghanistan','albania','algeria'];

const answerSet = new Set(answer)

const newCountries = countries.filter(c => !answerSet.has(c.ChoicesName))

console.log(newCountries)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var countries = 
[
{ChoicesID: 1, ChoicesName : 'afghanistan'},
{ChoicesID: 2, ChoicesName : 'albania'},
{ChoicesID: 3, ChoicesName : 'algeria'},
{ChoicesID: 4, ChoicesName : 'angola'},
{ChoicesID: 5, ChoicesName : 'argentina'},
{ChoicesID: 6, ChoicesName : 'armenia'}
];

var answer = ['afghanistan','albania','algeria'];

var NewCountries = countries.filter(o => !answer.includes(o.ChoicesName))

console.log(NewCountries)
```

like this?

Answer (score 1):

```js
var countries = [
    { ChoicesID: 1, ChoicesName: "afghanistan" },
    { ChoicesID: 2, ChoicesName: "albania" },
    { ChoicesID: 3, ChoicesName: "algeria" },
    { ChoicesID: 4, ChoicesName: "angola" },
    { ChoicesID: 5, ChoicesName: "argentina" },
    { ChoicesID: 6, ChoicesName: "armenia" },
  ];
  var answer = ["afghanistan", "albania", "algeria"];
  var filteredArray = countries.filter(
    (country) => !answer.includes(country.ChoicesName)
  );
  console.log(filteredArray);
```